# Asp.net hashing (using codesmith) when upgrading from .net 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, upgrade

I'm administrating servers running IIS 6, hosting a website on ASP.NET 2.0. Yesterday I installed .Net framework 3.5, and all my user authentication system was lost. Users can't log in, because their password arn't getting authenticated, maybe because the hash function has changed in 3.5??? I can't really get to the code, but I know it uses an extention called CodeSmith.

Do you know of any break my upgrade the 3.5 ugrade could couse?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autogenerated machineKeys in `machine.config` might be the cause. The passwords might have been hashed with a different [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx). If this is the case there's nothing you could do other than resetting all the passwords and explicitly specify a machine key.